# A polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ not generated by $5$ and $x^2+2$.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I want to show that the ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$ generated by the polynomials $5$ and $f(x)=x^2+2$ is strictly included in $\mathbb Z[x]$ so I wanted to find a polynomial $P\in \mathbb Z[x]$ that cannot be generated by $5$ and $f(x)$. I took $P=X^2+1$ and then I supposed that there exist $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $X^2+1=5 Q(x)+ (x^2+2)R(x)$ then in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ this would give $(x-2)(x-3)=(x^2+2)Q(x)$ which implies that $(x^2+2)Q(x)$ is reducible modulo 5 which is not true because $x^2+2$ is not reducible modulo 5. Hence $x^2+1$ cannot be generated by $5$ and $f(x)=x^2+2$ is this reasoning correct and is there any easier way to find such an example.

Comment: If an ideal doesn't isn't the whole ring, there is one element for sure you know it cannot contain. Can you determine what that element is and show it is not obtained in this way?

Comment: yes it is $1$, but how to show that $1$ is not generated by $5$ and $x^2+2$

Comment: oh it means $x^2+2$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ which is not the case.